# Android OpenGL ES Support Everywhere?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I need to get an idea of how many potential installs I'll be loosing if I choose to do my drawing in OpenGL instead of android's native 2D graphics APIs in android.graphics.*

The android documentation seems to imply that the OpenGL ES API is supported basically on all phones: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html

```
OpenGL ES 2.0 is supported by most Android devices
```

Now, does that imply that even cheap commodity devices will have OpenGL ES 2.0 support? Will the cheaper phones perhaps have software rendering, or will it always be hardware rendering?

I take it that the documentation's wording of "most android devices" means that there may indeed be some phones which are running android-8, but just don't have the hardware for OpenGL ES 2.0. But how many phones is that exactly?

Answer (score 17):

Check the [Device Dashboard](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#OpenGL) by OpenGL ES version.

Comment: Dude, that is seriously amazing. +1 for finding that link.

Comment: The requested URL was not found on this server.

Comment: The link is fixed.