# Android devices 480x800 and more with OpenGL ES 1.1 support only

Tags: android, opengl-es

My application target is devices with the **resolution 480x800 and more**. I have a choose to use old cocos2d-x( with support GLES 1.1 ) or new one( with only support GLES 2.0 ) for my project. 
I have read http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html. 
But still have a question: **how many devices with resolution 480x800 and more have no  GLES 2.0 support?**

Answer (score 0):

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964248/android-opengl-es-support-everywhere) contains a [link to various statistics](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html).

The raw data is not available, unfortunately, so it will be some kind of guesswork. Note the data has been collected in October 2012.

- > 90% of the devices have OpenGL ES 2.0 support.
- Screen size is more involved, since this is done density independent. Hopefully, these are reasonable assumptions: taking everything from `normal+hdpi/xhdpi`, `large+mdpi/xhdpi`, and `xlarge+mpdi`, >85% of all devices have screens with at least 800x480 resolution.

Perhaps these two number can be combined using statistics fu, I don't know.

Comment: Indeed, current Android dashboard has 1.1 only at 9.2%. For new development you may just be able to ignore this subset of devices depending on what you're doing.